# Drop-down box that expands towards the left

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word

I've designed a Pane for Microsoft Word in a Visual Studio C# project and have just run into a little annoyance.

Essentially the values in a drop-down box are quite lengthy and are running off the right-hand side of the screen (seeing that the pane is on the right as well).  So I was just wondering if anyone's aware of a way to have the drop-down items box **expand towards the left instead of the right**?

Comment: Please don't use the `code highlighter` to `highlight` lots of different `words`, it makes it quite `hard` to read. `:)`

Comment: you need to change your css i think..

Comment: `Sorry!` @GeorgeDuckett  :)  Thanks @Rahul but I don't think CSS applies as it's an Office project

Comment: OK looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree, perhaps we'll just move the pane to the left!